# Why does the change of variable theorem hold even with zero derivative somewhere?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $g: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable, and let $f: g([a, b]) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. (Here $g([a,b])$ denotes the image of $[a,b]$ under the map $g$.) The change of variable theorem says that
$$
\int_a^b (f \circ g) \cdot g’ = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f.
$$

Sometimes I have seen the result stated with the additional hypothesis that $g’(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. Then by continuity of $g’$ and the Intermediate Value Theorem, $g’$ keeps a constant sign on $(a, b)$, so that $g$ takes $[a, b]$ in a strictly monotonic fashion onto the interval whose endpoints are $g(a)$ and $g(b)$.

However, it seems the theorem actually holds even if we don’t assume that $g’(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. I would like to get some intuition as to why the result holds even in this case.

I do not need a formal proof (unless the details are necessary to understanding the intuition); I have seen the proof that uses the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and I can follow the logic, but am not sure about the rough idea/picture. For example, why intuitively can the integral be evaluated from $g(a)$ to $g(b)$, even though it seems like these are not necessarily the endpoints of $g([a,b])$? And can't $g$ map $[a,b]$ in a non-strictly-monotonic or non-invertible fashion onto $g([a,b])$?

Also, is it true for the general multivariate case? Do we need an assumption of non-zero-ness? Sometimes I see some assumption like non-zero determinant of the Jacobian or something on some set, whereas sometimes this condition seems to not be mentioned. (I'm vaguely recollecting what I've come across, and I'm not very familiar with the result, so I might be wrong here.)

Comment: Its even more general than this, the derivative can change sign. In 1D, to go from $a$ to $b$, you will have to go through all real number between them an odd number of times. Each contribution cancels by pair and you are only left with 1 "go through". This explains why it does not hold in general for larger dimensions and why more hypothesis are needed, as there are many ways to go from one point to another.